# Facebook Like button - how to get the number of friends who 'liked' something

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Is it possible to get the number of a *user's friends* who clicked 'Like' on a particular item on a page on my site? i.e. something along the lines of '45 of your friends Like this'.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks all, for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a like button on a website, facebook renders it in the following format:

a) if the current user is logged in on facebook: Friend 1, Friend 2 and x others like this (or just the number of total likers if no friend like that)

b) if the current user is not logged in: x people like this.

In order to get the above result, you need to use standard layout and to have `show_faces` value set to `true`. If you want to customize that, you have to use the Graph API/FQL. But it is not that simple :)

Answer (score 2):

I did have the exact same issue, and I'm not satisfied with the option `show_faces` cause I wanted to have an integer value.

I found the solution using FQL query :

```
select uid from page_fan where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND page_id ='000000000'
```

it will give you a list in json, using `.length` will give you the number!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook can do all the hardwork for you and generate a like button:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Comment: Thanks Matt. I've already used that to generate the like button iframe code, but it just shows the total number of likes as opposed to that plus 'xx of your friends like this'.

Comment: @karim when you put a like button on a website, facebook renders it in the following format: a) if the current user is logged in on facebook: `Friend 1, Friend 2 and x others like this` (or just the number of total likers if no friend like that) b) if the current user is not logged in: `x people like this`. If you want to customize that, you have to use the Graph API/FQL. But it is not that simple :)

Comment: @misterjinx - any idea which option does that? Even when I am logged in, I like something, and have a friend like it, it will still just say '2 people like this'.

Comment: @karim yes, you need to use standard layout and to have `show_faces` value set to true. i used this at one of my sites and worked smoothly as described earlier :)

Comment: @misterjinx - I suggest you post that as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, checkout Facebook's API. Facebook "Objects" that can be liked have the 'likes' property.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin with this. Basically, I already have 'Like' buttons on each item on my site. What I want is the number of my friends who have liked each item - I don't need to store it, just display it to other people who are signed in. What do you mean by Facebook "Objects" that can be liked have the 'likes' property?

Comment: you get it wrong. he asked to know how any of  the total `likers` are friends with the respective user